# Tab border to align with full width border

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am trying to achieve something like this in HTML/CSS (TailwindCSS):

[image: tab border]

Notice how the border on the active tab aligns perfectly with the full-width border.

**CODE**:

Here is my HTML which includes the tailwind css classes.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="bg-slate-800 rounded-md mb-5 p-8">
    <ul class="flex items-center mb-4 border-b-2">
        <li class="p-4 border-b-2 border-red-500">
            <a href="" class="font-semibold block">First Tab</a>
        </li>
        <li class="p-4">
            <a href="" class="font-semibold block">Second Tab</a>
        </li>
        <li class="p-4">
            <a href="" class="font-semibold block">Third Tab</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  <div>
    tab content
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice how the red border isn't perfectly aligned to the full-width border.

How can I get things perfectly aligned?

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D. Although I had seen snippets on the site before, I wasn't sure how to create them myself. Today was my chance to learn! I've now added a snippet. :)

Comment: What you are seeing is entirely logical. The border of the `li` is *inside* the `ul` which has it's own border. You'd have to drop the `li` by the width of it's border. So something like `margin-bottom: -2px` so that the `li` now covers the `ul` border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `li` is within the `ui` , so the when you apply border to `li` you push the entire `ul`, so giving a negative margin of the width of border of `ul` to `li`  i.e `2px` fixes this problem.

Just add `-mb-[2px]` in the active div

```
<div class=" rounded-md mb-5 p-8">
  <ul class="flex items-center mb-4 border-b-2">
    <li class="p-4 border-b-2 border-red-500 -mb-[2px]">
      <a href="" class="font-semibold  ">
        First Tab
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="p-4 ">
      <a href="" class="font-semibold ">
        Second Tab
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="p-4">
      <a href="" class="font-semibold ">
        Third Tab
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div>tab content</div>
</div>
```

Before
[image]

After
[image]